# Add prefix to img src with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can I add a prefix to every img src?

```
<div id="div_1">
    <h1> Title 1 </h1>
    <div><img src="blah.jpg" /></div>
    <div><p> Lorem Ipsum </p></div>
</div>
<div id="div_2">
    <h1> Title 2 </h1>
    <div><img src="blah2.jpg" /></div>
    <div><p> Lorem Ipsum </p></div>
</div>
<div id="div_3">
    <h1> Title 3 </h1>
    <div><img src="blah3.jpg" /></div>
    <div><p> Lorem Ipsum </p></div>
</div>
```

Every img src should look like  this:

```
<img src="prefix/blah.jpg" />
<img src="prefix/blah2.jpg" />
<img src="prefix/blah3.jpg" />
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery:**

Using jQuery to change all images on page http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/FnPd5/

```
$('img').each(function(){ this.src='prefix/'+this.src })
```

jQuery way to find images on in divs starting with `div_`: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/FnPd5/2/

```
jQuery("[id^='div_']").each(function(){
    var img = $(this).find('img')[0];
    img.src='prefix/'+img.src
})
```

---

**Vanilla Javascript**

Vanilla Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/FnPd5/1/

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = items.length; i--;) {
    var img = items[i];
    img.src='prefix/'+img.src;
}
```

Vanilla Javascript to find images on in divs starting with `div_`: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/FnPd5/3/

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if(divs[i].id.indexOf('div_') == 0) {
        var img = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
        img.src='prefix/'+img.src;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will work for all images inside the page , not for those inside div_?

Comment: Is it mentioned in question?

Comment: i guess he would to add it only for this part of code,anyway you are right , he didn't specified

Comment: example added based on your comment :)

Comment: Based on my answer too haha , just kidding

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NVj6c/)

```
$("[id^='div_'] img").each(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  var newSrc="prefix/"+src;
  $(this).attr("src",newSrc)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $('img').each(function(i,e){
     $(e).attr('src','prefix/'+$(e).attr('src'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution based on your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div div img').each(function(){ 
   var imagen = $(this).attr('src') ;
   $(this).attr("src","prefix/"+imagen);
});
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/kR5ZW/

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src')
    $(this).attr('src','prefix/'+imgSrc);
})
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NaQ78/)**

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
$('img').attr('src', function(ii, oldSrc) {
    return 'prefix/' + oldSrc;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addPrefixToImg(prefix) {
    $( "img" ).each(function( index ) {
        this.src = prefix + this.src;
    });
}

addPrefixToImg('prefix/');
```

you can test on http://jsfiddle.net/f32MQ/